# How to get all source code for Grails in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

It's really frustrating not being able to step through source code when working with a grails project in IntelliJ. I have grails 2.2.1 and IntelliJ 12.1.4 ultimate.

I'm fighting with an issue with Apache CXF and stepping through the CXF source would easily help me track it down. Is there some way to just flip a switch in IntelliJ so it will go download all the source for grails and its dependencies (including CXF) so I can do so?

Comment: Post IntelliJ v11, you can [download sources](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/10/new-in-11-downloading-sources-of-third-party-jars-from-web/) easily. I have seen it also downloads the related sources for that particular class.

Answer (score 1):

I use IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4 and Grails 2.1.0. To view sources of a 3rd-party jar after I open a .class file I click "Search in internet..." and it always finds these sources. This feature had not been working for some previous Idea versions, but it works perfectly for me in 12.1.X.

Comment: +1 - I should have known that IntelliJ would solve the problem easily and elegantly.  Best IDE on the market, hands down.